# impossible to attribute with a simple $_POST

Tags: php, post

I have a weird weird weird problem.
I call a page "afficher_messages.php" with the POST method. In this page there is the following code :

```
$nb_messages = 5;
if (isset($_POST['nb_messages']))
{
   echo "nb_messages = " . $_POST['nb_messages'] . "</br>";
   $nb_messages = $_POST['nb_messages'];
}
```

But I have the error 500.

If I comment like that :

```
$nb_messages = 5;
if (isset($_POST['nb_messages']))
{
   echo "nb_messages = " . $_POST['nb_messages'] . "</br>";
   //$nb_messages = $_POST['nb_messages'];
}
```

Then it prints : nb_messages = 11. So $_POST['nb_messages'] exists and its value is 11.

If I do that :

```
$nb_messages = 5;
if (isset($_POST['nb_messages']))
{
   echo "nb_messages = " . $_POST['nb_messages'] . "</br>";
   $nb_messages = 11;
}
```

It works... But it is not what I want because $_POST['nb_messages'] is not always 11.

To sum up, $_POST['nb_messages'] has a value but I can't attribute it to $nb_messages.

Comment: Did you try looking at the php error logs, to see if you can get a more informative error message?

Comment: Every time you have an error 500, you have to look at the error log and you know what went wrong. You could also set display errors on.

Comment: Certainly there is just a typo.

Comment: I just asked the admin of the server to check the error log. I tell you once I know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it was a problem of type later in the code.
I had this line : $reponse->bindValue('nb_messages', $nb_messages, PDO::PARAM_INT);

And I needed to cast $nb_messages like that :
$reponse->bindValue('nb_messages', (int)$nb_messages, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Answer (score 1):

your code looks fine. Once you try:

```
$nb_messages = 5;
if (isset($_POST['nb_messages']))
{
     $nb_messages = $_POST['nb_messages'];
     echo "nb_messages = " . $nb_messages . "</br>";
}
```

Comment: I tried but I have exactly the same problem..
but thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_POST['nb_messages'])){
  $nb_msg= $_POST['nb_messages'];
  echo $nb_msg;
  $nb_messages= $nb_msg;
  echo $nb_messages;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: I Tried but I have exactly the same problem too..
But yes, it is what I'm trying to do !